# Double backslash in zsh is interpreted to a single backslash ('\\' -> \)

Tags: shell, command-line, escaping, zsh, oh-my-zsh

In zsh:

```
>> echo '\\'
\
```

I expected strings between single quotes to be not interpreted at all, (bash would show //). So I wonder why zsh turns the double backslash here into a single backslash.

Maybe this is an option I can set?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure you aren't thinking of `echo '\\'`, which would output a single backslash?

Comment: @chepner Whoops, it is indeed the other way around. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
➜  ~ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
➜  ~ echo "//"
//
➜  ~ echo '//'
//
➜  ~ echo //
//
➜  ~ echo "\/"
\/
➜  ~ echo '\/'
\/
➜  ~ echo \/
/
➜  ~ which echo
echo: shell built-in command
➜  ~
```

You may noticed that the zsh has its own built-in echo, therefore you can control the behaviour you expect by the -e/-E option. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html

```
➜  ~ echo -E '\\'
\\
➜  ~ echo -e '\\'
\
➜  ~ echo -e '//'
//
➜  ~ echo -E '//'
//
➜  ~
```

Comment: The OP claims to get a single slash from `echo '//'`. This doesn't provide any explanation for how that could be possible.

Comment: Also, the value of `$SHELL` doesn't tell you what shell is *currently* running, only what shell serves as your login shell.

Answer (score 0):

`echo`, by default, is POSIX-compliant in `zsh`, which means that `echo` itself will treat certain pairs of characters starting with `\` specially. It is true that inside single quotes, nothing is escaped. A single backslash can appear inside single quotes:

```
% echo '\'
\
```

Two backslashes can also be passed to `echo` using `'\\'`. However, now `echo` *itself* treats `\\` as a pair representing a single backslash, because certain other pairs are treated specially. Just to name two, `\t` represents a horizontal tab

```
% echo 'a\tb'
a   b
```

while `\n` represents a linefeed

```
% echo 'a\nb'
a
b
```

That means to be able to print the two characters `\` and `n`, for example, you need some way of specifying a backslash without it escaping the following `n`. That way is with `\\`:

```
% echo '\\n'
\n
```